# "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" while writing a file

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to serialize an object using binary serialization and some helpers taken from [WPPerfLab](https://github.com/jevgenidotnet/WPPerfLab/tree/master/WPPerfLab/WPPerfLab.Common/Serialization/Binary) and I've got the error in this line:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
```

Here's a short snippet of what I'm doing.

```
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(FileName))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(FileName);
            }                
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
            {                                        
                new BinarySerializationHelper().Serialize(fileStream, object);
            }
    }
```

After some googling I found out that this may be a stream related error but I'm quite sure that there's no other stream which has opened the file that I'm trying to write to (the name is also random!).

So, how do I solve this one?

Comment: where is this snippet being invoked? are you sure it is not being called more than once with the same file name?

Comment: It's called just once by a button (and I'm clicking just once!) and it's in a static method (something like `DataManager.saveData(object)`). The filename depends on both the hashCode and the current date/time.

Answer (score 0):

I found your error brother. Actually, the cause of error is not IsolatedStorageFileStream but the innocent looking string FileName.

I suppose you are generating FIleName as

string FileName = "some_random_string"+DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");

or whatever format of datetime you are using. Put a breakpoint on this line. You will find the FileName value contains a character ':' ....WHICH IS VERY VERY BAD naming. Hence the error. Try to name the file other way.

But this IsolatedStorageFileStream constructor bugs me very much. So I use another way. I am using method of IsolateStorage stream to open file. Look at the code

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(FileName))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(FileName);
        }                
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
        {                                        
            new BinarySerializationHelper().Serialize(fileStream, object);
        }
}
```